# How to create a number with (f)16 repeating n times?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, bitmask

I need to create a number where (f)<sub>16</sub> repeats n times. 0 <  n <= 16.

I tried the following for example for n = 16

```
std::cout << "hi:" << std::hex << std::showbase << (1ULL << 64) - 1 << std::endl;
```

> warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
> std::cout << "hi:" << std::hex << std::showbase << (1ULL << 64) - 1 << std::endl;
> ^  ~~ 1 warning generated.
>
> hi:0x200

How can I get all digits `f` without overflowing `ULL` ?

Comment: Try using a multiple of `4` as the magic number you shift by.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that fails for n = 16 as the magic number then would be 64 which overflows ULL

Comment: Do you understand what the fs mean? What would the value of a number with 16 fs be? Calculate that.

Comment: To state what people have been hinting at: If `unsigned long long` has 64 bits, then `(1ULL << 64) - 1` has well-defined and portable behavior and will give value `0xffffffffffffffffULL`.

Comment: @aschepler: `1ULL << 64` does not have well-defined or portable behavior. Per C++ draft N4659 8.8 1, “The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.”

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Using a variable might evade the warning but not the undefined behavior. Per my quote from the C++ standard above, shifting by as many bits as there are in the type is not defined by the standard, regardless of whether the shift amount is constant or not.

Comment: My mistake for n = 16. So to make it simple: Add a special case for `n == 16`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's to be used in a macro, and I'm trying to avoid long expressions. Didn't mean to make it a codegolf, sorry.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is `int n = 16;
    std::cout << "hi:" << std::hex << std::showbase << (1ULL << n*4) - 2 << std::endl;` also correct (`hi:0xffffffffffffffff`) due to  undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @puio: The behavior in that case is also not defined by the C++ standard, because `<< n*4` shifts by 64 bits but the width of `unsigned long long` in your implementation is 64 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for explaining and taking time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For n = 1 to 16, you could start with all Fs and then shift accordingly:

```cpp
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL >> (4*(16-n));
```

(handle n=0 separately)

Comment: This fits my needs the best!

Comment: This just flips the special case you need to handle. The real problem is that there are 65 possible values of `n`, 0 to 64 inclusive, but << and >> only can handle 64 possible values.

Comment: @MSalters nobody asked it so far. thanks for asking, n cannot be 0. other answers are great. Please upvote them. Asker should accept what helps them the most. I was torn between this and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156781/14170429

Comment: If you need to handle n=0, there's always ` (n==0)?0ULL : 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL >> (4*(16-n))`

Answer (score 3):

> where (f)16 repeats n times.

If I understood that correctly, I believe that's trivial. Add one `f`. Shift the number to the left by 4 bits. Add another `f`. Shift to the left 4 bits. Add another `f`. Repeat `n` times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long long gen(unsigned n) {
     unsigned long long r = 0;
     while (n--) {
         r <<= 4;
         r |= 0xf;
     }
     return r;
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        printf("%d -> %llx\n", i, gen(i));
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> f
2 -> ff
3 -> fff
4 -> ffff
5 -> fffff
6 -> ffffff
7 -> fffffff
8 -> ffffffff
9 -> fffffffff
10 -> ffffffffff
11 -> fffffffffff
12 -> ffffffffffff
13 -> fffffffffffff
14 -> ffffffffffffff
15 -> fffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Yes you got that correctly! Thanks. Sorry for the C/C++ confusion. I didn't think that bit operations would be wildly different in the two languages. I'll accept the most concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since shifting by `4*n` bits is problematic if `n` is 16 and `unsigned long long` is 64 bits, you can solve the problem by shifting by a smaller amount. If `n` is known to be positive, we can partition it into two shifts:

```
(1ull << 4 << 4*(n-1)) - 1u
```

And, since `1ull << 4` is a constant, we can replace it:

```
(0x10ull << 4*(n-1)) - 1u
```

If `n` can be zero, then, to support any value from 0 to 16, we cannot use a single expression. A solution is:

```
n ? 0 : (0x10ull << 4*(n-1)) - 1u
```

Comment: By using sign-extending shifts, the case with any value from 0 to 16 can also be handled by a single expression, for example `uint64_t(int64_t(-n) >> 63) >> ((-n << 2) & 63)` or `int64_t(n - 0x8000000000000010) >> (~(n << 2) & 63)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interrested in in hex format and the digit `f`, use the other answers.

The function below can generate the number for both hex and decimal formats and for any digit.

```
#include <iostream>

uint64_t getNum(uint64_t digit, uint64_t times, uint64_t base)
{
    if (base != 10 && base != 16) return 0;
    if (digit >= base) return 0;
    
    uint64_t res = 0;
    uint64_t multiply = 1;
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    {
        res += digit * multiply;
        multiply *= base;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getNum(3, 7, 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << getNum(0xa, 14, 16) << std::dec << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3333333
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

notice: The current code has no overflow detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate function looking for example the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long create_hex( size_t n )
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    
    n %= 2 * sizeof( unsigned long long );

    while ( n-- )
    {
        x = x << 4 | 0xf;
    }
    
    return x;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i <= 16; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu -> %llx\n", i, create_hex( i ) );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 0
1 -> f
2 -> ff
3 -> fff
4 -> ffff
5 -> fffff
6 -> ffffff
7 -> fffffff
8 -> ffffffff
9 -> fffffffff
10 -> ffffffffff
11 -> fffffffffff
12 -> ffffffffffff
13 -> fffffffffffff
14 -> ffffffffffffff
15 -> fffffffffffffff
16 -> 0
```

As initially you was using two language tag, C and C++, then to run this program as a C++ program substitute the header `<stdio.h>` for `<iostream>` and use the operator << instead of the call of `printf`.

Comment: The first sentence of the question clearly states that n = 16 is included and should produce ffffffffffffffff (in base 16), and this answer shows the output for n = 16 is 0. How could this be a correct answer?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am considering this as a wrong condition.